# trying to log out but keep getting error Warning: Division by zero on line 4?

Tags: php, html, session

been playing around with the small project to log out but each time I'm trying to log out giving this error:

> Warning: Division by zero in /home2/beastly/public_html/test/logout.php on line 4
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/beastly/public_html/test/logout.php:4) in /home2/beastly/public_html/test/logout.php on line 4
>
> Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session in /home2/beastly/public_html/test/logout.php on line 8
> You will be forwarded in back to login screen If not Click Here

```
<?php
//remove PHPSESSID from browser
if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) )
setcookie( session_name(), â€œâ€, time()-3600, â€œ/â€ );
//clear session from globals
$_SESSION = array();
//clear session from disk
session_destroy(); here
```

Comment: The funky characters here should set off warning bells: `setcookie( session_name(), â€œâ€, time()-3600, â€œ/â€ );`

Comment: have changed over to this :

setcookie ("session_name", "", time() - 3600);

Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session in /home2/beastly/public_html/test/logout.php

Comment: `session_destroy()` is only useful if you've called `session_start()` at the top of your file. You can either delete the "destroy," or add a "start."

Comment: yes got it working thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code appears to have been mangled by an incorrect character set. If you look at line 4:

> ```
> setcookie( session_name(), â€œâ€, time()-3600, â€œ/â€ );
> ```

You'll notice that there is a division operator there.

If you turn on all errors, you'll see that it's also complaining about the "undefined constants" `â€œâ€`, `â€œ`, and `â€`. That last one, in a numeric context, resolves to zero, which is why you're getting the divide-by-zero error.

If you're getting the error `Trying to destroy uninitialized session` when you're calling `session_destroy()`, then the session doesn't actually exist. Did you call `session_start()` beforehand? You can't manipulate the session until you do.

Comment: yes correct i just realized I've adjusted to to : setcookie ("session_name", "", time() - 3600);
that sorted the problem but the still get error on the line 8

Comment: @CesarNagera What error on line 8? That's the `session_destroy()`. Your code doesn't actually have the "here" in it, does it?

Comment: that here is just when i was inserting the code to here loool

Comment: See above re: the unitialized session error. That should answer that.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: Division by zero in
>   /home2/beastly/public_html/test/logout.php on line 4

Is coming from here.. `â€œ/â€` .. that is supposed to be a file path, not.. whatever that is.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home2/beastly/public_html/test/logout.php:4) in
>   /home2/beastly/public_html/test/logout.php on line 4

The first error sends the headers preventing the session from starting. Fix the first one and this one will go away.

> Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to
>   destroy uninitialized session in
>   /home2/beastly/public_html/test/logout.php on line 8

This is because the headers got sent by the first error preventing the session from starting, so there isn't one to  destroy.

Fix the file path parameter and everything else will work again.